# How to show fivestar votes in views as number instead of percentage?

Tags: 7, views, rating

I have a view which show a content with a [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) field (votes).
The problem is that the field is shown as the percentage of votes, not like the stars, or the number (in fact I need to show the number instead of percentage).

I mean, my Fivestar field has 10 stars. Well then if, for example, a node has 7 stars, rather than see the 7 stars or the number of stars (7) is shown the percentage, 70.

What I have to do to show the number (in my example "7")?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my question: Hide your vote field in views ("Exclude from display"); then, add a Global field, the "global math expression", and in this field add a replacement token of your exclude field, in my case `[value]`. Finally add the mathematical expression to divide by 10 the number: `[value]/10`.
Apply and save the view.